# Invoke a stored procedure from a view in mysql. Is it possible? If not, any alternatives?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, view

I have a scenario where there is a View 'MyView', a Stored Procedure 'MyProc' and a Table 'MyTable'.

When MyProc is called, it clears the exisiting data in MyTable and based on certain conditions, fills MyTable with the right data. The job of the MyView is to return back the data contained in MyTable.

Eveytime MyView gets called, MyProc needs to be invoked to fill up MyTable.

The question is, how to link MyProc with MyView. Can a stored procedure be invoked from a view and if not, is there any other work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can a stored procedure be invoked from a view

**NO**, only a function can be used since views are nothing but stored/saved queries.

> is there any other work around?

Yes, you can probably as alternative wrap all this steps inside another stored procedure and call that procedure which will in-turn call your `myproc`